# Making Clones of Pico

Tags: pi-pico, setup

I am trying to find information to clone one pico with everything already set up and programmed to 5 new picos without manually copying the files and libraries. I am using Thonny to program them in MicroPython. Is this something that can be done quickly? I am setting up a project with 10 modules all the same and I don't want to have to manually copy each file one at a time to set up everything.

Comment: +1 That's an interesting proposition, but AFAIK, there's no existing solution to do that.

Comment: @Seamus I would think I am not the first person to want to do this. The pico is a really interesting microcontroller and I would like to use it in more of my work.